# route print jobs to different printers based on page count

Tags: printer, network-printer

Is it possible to route any job X pages and under to Printer A, and have any documents over X pages go to Printer B?  Preferably at the workstation itself, and not at the router/network level.

Solution must be software agnostic and work with any Windows version.

Comment: please include software and OS etc.

Comment: Any software on any windows platform.  The office uses multiple applications and has multiple computers.

Comment: I would imagine you need to setup a print server and mess around with it. How do you plan on notifying the user which printer the job went to?

Answer (score 1):

I [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=route+print+jobs+to+different+printers+based+on+page+count) your exact question and it gave me several good software solutions on the first 2 pages. So, are you willing to pay for such a solution?

The first I clicked was [Papercut](http://www.papercut.com/tour/advanced-scripting/). It states:

> Automatically route **large jobs** to more efficient high volume printers.

Second i clicked was [Print Evolve Suite](http://www.capellatech.com/Products/Print-Evolve-Suite):

> For instance, IPM can automatically route all monochrome print jobs to a high-speed monochrome printer. It can mandate that multi-page documents be output in duplex mode (a critical capability for companies looking to work “leaner and greener”), or that all e-mail or web page printouts be in economode. It can even prevent certain types of jobs from being printed. On top of that, it requires absolutely no input from the end-user. Automatic notifications are available to make certain that the end-users are informed of changes to their print jobs.

You need to check yourself if this one can handle routing according to number of pages.

Third one was [OM Plus from Plus technoligies](http://www.plustechnologies.com/PrintSolutions/PrintJobRouting.aspx):

> Additionally, print jobs can be automatically re-routed by OM Plus from network printers to a large central printer **if they exceed a certain number of pages** (or other criteria). At that time, the end user receives an email instructing them how to pick up their re-directed job. This improves throughput by utilizing a higher volume (and usually lower cost) printer.

Answer (score 0):

With [Print&Share](http://www.printandshare.info) you can just do this.

Print&Share allows you to create profiles, where each profile can contain one or multiple channels. A channel can be a printer, email, file printer, fax, etc...

Channels can use Trigger points. For a Printer channel you can enable these options:

```
"Execute from: # pages"
```

This allows you to only execute a channel (and thus print) when a number of pages is met.

There is also another option:

```
"Execute up to a max. number of # pages"
```

This allows you to use a printer until the number of pages is too large.

Both options can check on the input or output (because you can insert documents or pages to the print job or deselect pages etc...):

```
"Pages to check: No. of pages to send (output)"
or 
"Pages to check: No. of pages of print job (input)"
```

In the Profile overview on the General tab, you can right mouse click a channel and select Ignore Errors.

You can find more information on: http://www.printandshare.info 
There is also a free 30-day trial.

**Update:**

I've created a video that demonstrates how you can do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03RbCbBkAL8&list=PLDF2C2AD95B2B2FC2&index=1

*Note: i'm affiliated with the software*